# How to stop user to add extra tag in SOAPUI request

Tags: web-services, wsdl

Below is my SOAP request:
    
       
       
          
             Aditya
             ?

```
My rest of the classes are:
HelloWorld.java
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

//Service Endpoint Interface
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface HelloWorld{

    @WebMethod String getHelloWorldAsString(String name, String company);

}

HelloWorldImpl.java:

import javax.jws.WebService;

import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.SchemaValidation;

//Service Implementation
//@SchemaValidation
@WebService(endpointInterface = "org.techsavvy.HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld{

    @Override
    public String getHelloWorldAsString(String name, String company) {

        return "Hello!! your name is " + name+ " and you work in " +company+ ".";


    }

}


HelloWorldPublisher.java

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import org.techsavvy.HelloWorldImpl;

//Endpoint publisher
public class HelloWorldPublisher{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9999/ws/hello", new HelloWorldImpl());

    }

}
```

Problem: I am running my webservice in SOAPUI by adding the wsdl path(http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl). Once the request is generated I am entering the values for  and  and it runs successfully.
I want that if I am adding any extra tag to my generated request, response should not be generated and system should throw an error.

NOTE: I am not using any framework.